# Categorical axis order in plotly.js

Tags: javascript, plotly

I have a plotly.js bar chart that I am trying to get the order of the categorical axis right. Each category has a single bar, but sometimes they are green and sometimes they are yellow. The bars should be in order from highest to lowest, but plotly seems to order them based on the different fills.

The data:

```
var data = [
  {
    "marker": {
        "color": "#006666"
    },
    "x": ["A:0122", "A:0121", "A:0434", "A:0838", "A:0083", "A:0081", "A:0687"],
    "y": [1246.0, 1096.0, 1000.0, 200.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    "name": "Green",
    "type": "bar"
  }, 
  {
    "marker": {
        "color": "#C87B31"
    },
    "x": ["A:0169", "A:0175"],
    "y": [270.0, 0.0],
    "name": "Yellow",
    "type": "bar"
  }
];
```

The layout:

```
var layout = {
    "margin": {
        "t": 0
    },
    "barmode": "stack",
    "tickangle": -90,
    "showlegend": true,
    "xaxis": {
        "title": "Idea",
        "tickmode": "array",
        "tickvals": ["A:0122", "A:0121", "A:0434", "A:0169", "A:0838", "A:0083", "A:0175", "A:0081", "A:0687"]
    },
    "yaxis": {
        "title": "Result"
    }
};
```

Other configuation:

```
{"showLink":false, "displaylogo":false}
```

But here is the result:

[image]

Notice that "A:0169" should be the fourth bar, but instead it is the last.

How do I get the bars to be in the order I specify in `tickvals`? Or can I specify their order in a different way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set `x` and `tickvals` to an ordered array then add the xaxis labels with `ticktext` i.e.
data:

```
    [{
    "marker": {"color": "#006666"},
    "x": [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8],
    "y": [1246.0, 1096.0, 1000.0, 200.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    "name": "Green",
    "type": "bar"
    }, {
    "marker": {"color": "#C87B31"},
    "x": [3, 6],
    "y": [270.0, 0.0],
    "name": "Yellow",
    "type": "bar"
    }],
```

layout:

```
    {
    "margin": {"t": 0},
    "barmode": "stack",
    "tickangle": -90,
    "showlegend": true,
    "xaxis": {
      "title": "Idea",
      "tickmode": "array",
      "tickvals": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
      "ticktext": ["A:0122", "A:0121", "A:0434", "A:0169", "A:0838", "A:0083",             
                   "A:0175", "A:0081", "A:0687"]
    },
    "yaxis": {
      "title": "Result"
    }}
```

[image]

alternatively, if you're only concerned about the color of the bars you can plot one trace and set color as an array:

```
    var data = [{
      "x": ["A:0122", "A:0121", "A:0434", "A:0169", "A:0838", "A:0083",  
            "A:0175", "A:0081", "A:0687"],
      "y": [1246.0, 1096.0, 1000.0, 270.0, 200.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
      "type": "bar",
      "marker": {"color": ["#006666", "#006666", "#006666", "#C87B31", 
                  "#006666", "#006666", "#C87B31", "#006666"]}
    }],
    layout = {
      "margin": {"t": 0},
      "xaxis": {"title": "Idea"},
      "yaxis": {"title": "Result"}
    };
```

Answer (score 6):

Since [Plotly.js 1.10.2](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/releases/tag/v1.10.2), you can use `categoryorder` and `categoryarray` to control the order of a categorical axis. This way you can keep `x` as a list of strings.

Usage:

```
var data = [
  {
    "x": ["A", "D", "B"],
    "y": [1, 2, 3],
    "type": "bar"
  }, 
  {
    "x": ["C", "E"],
    "y": [2, 3],
    "type": "bar"
}];

var layout = {
    "xaxis": {
        "categoryorder": "array",
        "categoryarray":  ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
    }
};
```

For your exact example:

```
var data = [{
    "marker": {
        "color": "#006666"
    },
    "x": ["A:0122", "A:0121", "A:0434", "A:0838", "A:0083", "A:0081", "A:0687"],
    "y": [1246.0, 1096.0, 1000.0, 200.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    "name": "Green",
    "type": "bar"
}, {
    "marker": {
        "color": "#C87B31"
    },
    "x": ["A:0169", "A:0175"],
    "y": [270.0, 0.0],
    "name": "Yellow",
    "type": "bar"
}];

var layout = {
    "margin": {
        "t": 0
    },
    "barmode": "stack",
    "tickangle": -90,
    "showlegend": true,
    "xaxis": {
        "title": "Idea",
        "categoryorder": "array",
        "categoryarray":  ["A:0122", "A:0121", "A:0434", "A:0169", "A:0838", "A:0083", "A:0175", "A:0081", "A:0687"]
    },
    "yaxis": {
        "title": "Result"
    }
};
```

Result:

[image]