# plotly have trace without data in legend

Tags: plotly

[As a follow on to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027334/categorical-axis-order-in-plotly-js)

Suppose I want to show a set of bars, where each bar could be one of the choices: A, B, or C, each which has a different color. I would like to show the bars, but also if none the bars fall into a particular category still have that category show up in the legend. Unfortunately the categories without colors seem to get dropped. Notice in this example how the category labeled 'C' which should be blue is dropped from the legend:

```
data = [
{
x: [1, 3, 4],
y: [20, 14, 23],
type: 'bar',
name: 'A',
marker: {color: '#00FFFF'}},
{
x: [2, 5, 6],
y: [8, 6, 2],
type: 'bar',
name: 'B',
marker: {color: '#FF00FF'}},
{
x: [],
y: [],
type: 'bar',
name: 'C'
marker: {color: '#FF0000'}}]
```

[image: Category C is not shown]

How would I be able to make sure C (or any color without data) always shows up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Traces with empty data arrays are assumed to be not visible. This is equivalent to setting `visible: false` in the trace object.

You can trick plotly by entering `null` values in the data arrays:

```
data = [{
  x: [1, 3, 4],
  y: [20, 14, 23],
  type: 'bar',
  name: 'A',
  marker: {color: '#00FFFF'}
}, {
  x: [2, 5, 6],
  y: [8, 6, 2],
  type: 'bar',
  name: 'B',
  marker: {color: '#FF00FF'}
}, {
  x: [null],
  y: [null],
  type: 'bar',
  name: 'C'
  marker: {color: '#FF0000'}
}]
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Perfect. I didn't realize that there would be a difference between using [] and using [null].

Comment: [] means it creates an empty array. [null] means it creates an array with exactly one element. And THIS element is null.

Comment: @etpinard Your answer is 2 years old. Is there in the current version of plotly an other solution to this topic without pushing "null" values to `x` and `y`? This is not good cause other code of me expects valid dates and data in the div.data. Maybe there is a config-flag like `showEmptyTracesInLegend` that I can set to `true`

Comment: For anyone stumbling over this in 2024, this approach works but set [None] instead of [Null].

Answer (score 0):

You could add initialize the third trace with a datapoint with zero height:

`{'x': [0], 'y': [0], 'type': 'bar'}`

[image: Bar chart example with plotly]
interactive example: https://plot.ly/~chris/16792.embed

you'll also probably want to remove the hover text if there is no data. customize hover text with hoverinfo (https://plot.ly/python/reference/#bar-hoverinfo).

`{'x': [0], 'y': [0], 'type': 'bar', 'hoverinfo': 'none'}`

example chart: https://plot.ly/~chris/16795.embed

Comment: I think this solution could cause problems with how the bars are rendered. For instance suppose I didn't want the y-axis to start at zero, now I would have to think about what the 0 bars would do.